# Environment Variable Keeps on changing back to it's original form on Linux (Fedora)

Tags: linux, shell

I have a JAVA_HOME variable, doing >`echo $JAVA_HOME` gives `"old/path/to/my/jdk.1.7"`. I go to terminal and do a `export JAVA_HOME=new/path/to/my/jdk.1.8.0` which works fine for the duration of the terminal session, but soon as I start a new tab/terminal instance and do a >`echo $JAVA_HOME` it gives me: `old/path/to/my/jdk.1.7`. What could I be doing wrong.

Comment: Ubuntu specific, but might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655641/set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

You have to include this `export` in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` so it is loaded every time you start a new session.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui I actually had already figured it out, I posted this question to help other people that might get this problem

Answer (score 3):

An environment variable set in a shell session persists only for the duration of that session. To persist the variable you need to set it every time a shell session is started using a script. There are several script files that exist for this purpose and are executed automatically by bash whenever it is invoked. Unfortunately, this is not as straightforward as it seems because bash can be invoked in different ways and each type of invocation executes different scripts.

For **interactive login** shell invocations (console, ssh, etc.), you can set the variable by adding the following line to *~/.bash_profile*, *~/.bash_login* or *~/.profile*. Bash will look for these files in order and execute the first one that is readable.

For **interactive non-login** shell invocations (subshells, terminals from graphical environments, etc.) use *~/.bashrc*. Note that some distros (Ubuntu) source *~/.bashrc* from *~/.bash_profile* so setting it here will set it for interactive logins as well.

```bsh
export JAVA_HOME=new/path/to/my/jdk.1.8.0
```

Also **non-interactive** shell invocations (shells invoked to to run a script) inherit the parent environment, but do not execute any startup scripts.

Additionally, for some distros (Ubuntu for example), the recommended file to edit is *~/.pam_environment*, but the syntax is slightly different and requires one expression per line.

```
JAVA_HOME DEFAULT=new/path/to/my/jdk.1.8.0
```

If you want the changes to be system-wide rather than user-specific use */etc/bash.bashrc*, */etc/profile* and */etc/environment* respectively.

For more information on the difference between these files see the following link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment

It might also be helpful to read the *INVOCATION* section of the BASH man file as there are so many circumstantial factors that influence what script gets run and when.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: +1 for good explanation, quite deeper than mine. Anyway, I also have to state that providing a very long answer to a short question can make people skip it and go for others _easier and faster to read and understand_

Comment: Thanks and I agree. The short answer will help those that need it fixed yesterday, the long answer will help those than want to understand what is happening.